passing a group of package(class) options in 1 key using l3keys2e in latex class
problem
I want to writing a docuementclass, called it foo.cls in the following context. Assume there is a document class called bar.cls, which can accept the following key-value(options):
\documentclass[twoside, fontset=linux, margin=left]{bar}

I want to pass these group of options twoside, fontset=linux, margin=left of this class bar.cls in my documentclass foo.cls using key bar-option. Then i can use my class like
\documentclass[
    otherkey=value1,
    bar-option={twoside, fontset=linux, margin=left},
    anotherkey=value2
]{foo}

but i don't know how to declare the key bar-option. Using .tl_set:N? Using .meta:nn? I've try something, see below:
try 1
% define keys
\keys_define:nn {foo/option}{
    ..., 
    bar-option   .tl_set:N   = \l__bar_option_tl,
    ...,
}

% process options
\ProcessKeysOptions{foo/option}
\PassOptionsToClass{\tl_use:N \l__bar_option_tl}{bar}
\LoadClass{bar}

after compiling, see these warning:
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [fontset, margin].

which means that the option fontset, margin didn't pass into class bar.cls(i see the ouput pdf, it's true that these options didn't pass into).

though i know it's impossible to working, i try this at first.

try 2
There are just 3 key-values, why can't i just re-decalre them in foo.cls in \keys_define:nn, see below
% define keys
\keys_define:nn {foo/option}{
    twoside      .bool_set:N = \l__foo_twoside_bool,
    twoside      .initial:n  = { false },
    fontset      .tl_set:N   = \l__foo_fontset_tl,
    fontset      .initial:n  = { windows },
    margin       .tl_set:N  = \l__foo_margin_tl,
    margin       .initial:n  = { right },
    ...,
}

% process options
\ProcessKeysOptions{foo/option}
\PassOptionsToClass{
    fontset=\tl_use:N \l__foo_fontset_tl,
    margin=\tl_use:N \l__foo_margin_tl
]{bar}
\LoadClass{bar}

though it's working in this way, when there are many key-values in class bar.cls, it's hard to write and maintain the foo.cls.
try 3
I see that these key-values have been declared in class bar.cls, all declared in subkey bar/option, that's
bar / otherkey
bar / option
        / fontset
        / margin
        / twoside
bar / anotherkey

I import these key-values into my class foo.cls. Use .meta:nn to set them, see below:
\LoadClass{bar}

% define keys
\keys_define:nn {foo/option}{
    ...,
    bar-option   .meta:nn    = { bar / option }{#1},
    ...,
}

% process options
\ProcessKeysOptions{foo/option}

These key-values twoside, fontset=linux, margin=left didn't pass into the class bar.cls as well (Didn't make any changes in the ouput pdf when i add these options). May be bar.cls load before these keys in bar/option have been assigned. But bar.cls can't be load after command \keys_define:nn, it will raise undefined error (key-values bar/option undefined)
what i prefer
"try 2" working but will get worse when there are a number of keys. Can this problem been solved in an good way like "try3"(i don't need to re-decare these keys in bar.cls)?

Why don't you just pass all unknown options to bar?

You should avoid your try 3, it relies on undocumented internals of another class. The only thing that's documented is that it accepts options via LaTeX's standard interface to declare options.

Oh, my comment above is obviously only true if the used l3keys path isn't documented, if the l3keys-layer is documented as well you could use try 3.

Short elaboration why your try 1 didn't work: Depending on the used options interface, only the first token of the options list is expanded once before the class parses the list, \tl_use:N needs more than a single step to expand, hence you got the wrong results. Either use \PassOptionsToClass { \l__foo_bar_options_tl } { bar } or \exp_args:NV \PassOptionsToClass \l__foo_bar_options_tl { bar }.

Aside: Please note that your variable names aren't conforming to the naming convention. The tl holding the options to be forwarded to bar belongs to your module/class, hence should be named \l__foo_bar_options_tl, the first word after the underscores indicates the module to which the variable belongs, here foo, not bar.

I always get confused by macro expansion in LaTeX3. After receiving your response and reviewing the documentation interface3.pdf, I believe I have grasped some of the macro expansion rules. Thank you.

Why don't you use the straight forward method of directly forwarding the argument to bar-option:
% define keys
\keys_define:nn {foo/option}{
    ..., 
    bar-option   .code:n   = \PassOptionsToClass{#1}{bar},
    bar-option   .usage:n  = load,
    ...,
}

% process options
\@ifundefined{ProcessKeyOptions}
  {%
    \RequirePackage{l3keys2e}%
    \ProcessKeysOptions{foo/option}
  }
  {\ProcessKeyOptions[foo/option]} % use LaTeX's new interface if available

\LoadClass{bar}


Sorry for replying to your answer so late. Thank you, this solve my problem. I also find a solution by use bar-option  .clist_gset:N = \g__foo_bar_option_clist.
